# Chrome Remote Debugging: Inspect fails, flashes new window momentarily

Tags: chrome-for-android, usb-debugging, remote-control

I'm trying to use [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), and seem to be having a different problem from most folks.  The chrome://inspect window lists tabs ok, and the "open" and "reload" functions work properly.  But when I try to inspect, my Mac briefly flashes open a new window, then closes it a fraction of a second later.

Any thoughts on how to debug this or what's causing it?  Any logs I should be looking at?  I'm not trying to use port forwarding or localhost.  Gear:

Phone: Verizon Samsung S5, Android 5.0, Chrome 49
Mac: OSX El Capitan, Chrome 48

Comment: I would suggest trying a more recent Chrome version on desktop. Currently your desktop version is older than the mobile version, which is not good. You can install the newest Chrome version on Mac via the Canary channel: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: @MikhailNaganov Thanks for the idea, but I found that it works fine with a tablet running Chrome 47.  So that's not it.  I can do what I need with the tablet, so I'm good now.

Comment: Not sure why are you disagreeing -- you now use the mobile Chrome version which is smaller than your desktop version -- that's exactly what I was proposing to do. The only difference is that I was proposing to upgrade your desktop version instead of downgrading your mobile version, which is what you effectively did.

Comment: @MikhailNaganov You're right, of course - I got myself confused.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same flashing open and then close on clicking "inspect"  on the d. Desktop Chrome: 51.0.2693.2 dev (64-bit) on ubuntu linux . Phone:  Nexus 5 , Android 6.0.1 . Bizarrly, the same phone/cable have inspect open fine when i connect it to my mac.

Comment: I  just tried installing google stable, 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit), on linux as well and that time remote inspect worked! Maybe it's broken on some unstable versions of chrome for some OSs. It's handy to have more than one chrome channel version on the same machine. So that's my workaround.  I filed a bug with the chrome team so maybe it will get fixed in the future.